# Get Id when chart box is clicked

Tags: asp.net, google-visualization, orgchart

I am using Google Visualization API Org Chart to generate a hierarchy. When the chart is generated, I want to get the ID from the box which was clicked.

I am passing ID and Name as string to generate the chart. I want to pick the Id when any box is clicked and want to store this in a Session Variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can get the html from a node within the org chart.

```
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Question/Answer');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Prev_Question');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Count');
        data.addRows(tree_data);
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {
            allowHtml:true,
            allowCollapse:true
        });

        var selectHandler = function(e) {
            // get the selected node.
            var nodes = chart.getSelection();
            // get the node row id.
            var node_row = nodes[0].row;
            // get the node data.
            var node = data.xf[node_row].c;
            // select just the text from the node.
            var node_text = node[0].f;
            // out put the text.
            console.log(node_text);
        }

        // add event listening.
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

node_text, is the nodes html that you should have.